# Understanding dart syntax

Tags: dart

Coming from the java world I have difficulties to understand this code-fragment from the [AngularDart pirate badge code lab](https://github.com/dartlangfr/ng-darrrt-codelab):

```dart
    Future _loadData() {
        return _http.get('piratenames.json').then((HttpResponse response) {
          PirateName.names = response.data['names'];
          PirateName.appellations = response.data['appellations'];
        });
      }
    }
```

From my understanding PirateName is a class and how can the line

```dart
    PirateName.names = response.data['names'];
```

write a field of a class without referring to an actual instance?

Comment: That might a `static variable`? Dart syntax allows static variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart syntax allows static variables as does Java.

That is a `static variable` as defined in the source you provided `Edit piratebadge.dart` and you'll see where it is defined as static.